# SVG click events not firing/bubbling when using <use> element

Tags: jquery, svg, click, blink

I have come across an interesting bug (?) whereby if you embed the SVG using <use> as part of a link (an icon for example) – the icon itself does not register a click event in jQuery, but clicking the text does. I think this is due to SVG events not bubbling up?

If you embed the SVG directly, the link triggers regardless of whether you click the text or the icon.

A simple test case I created can be seen here:
[SVG <use> bug test case](http://codepen.io/greenchameleondesign/pen/tubJz).

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to fire if you use $('.element').click(function(){ ... }) rather than $(document).on('click', '.element', function(){ ... });

Comment: I've reported https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=382872 for Blink (Chrome/Opera).

Comment: I'm having the same issue when svg is embedded as <object>

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use `pointer-events: none;` on the svg. It worked for me.

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events
>   may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
>   events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Thanks @Omar that's a clever trick! I think this has been fixed in Chrome now and I've not come across it since. But if I do I'll definitely keep it in mind. Might be useful for other issues too.

Comment: My pleasure. I came across the problem with Safari.

Comment: Good answer. I've also found that if embedding an SVG using an object, the CSS declaration that you mentioned should be applied to the object rather than the SVG.

Comment: At the point of writing this comment, I didn't need pointer-events for chrome and firefox, but for IE-11 it needed this workaround or else the events would not fire.

Comment: I had the same problem but only present on IE10+. This fix worked for me, thanks!

Comment: im screwed... it doesn't work on Bootstrap Dropdown. I have pointer-events: none on every svg in my page, but in Edge fails... <use> swallows the click event. This is ridiculous.

Comment: This is very strange. I had to use `pointer-events: all;` to make svg-elements fire click events, not none. This answer was misleading for me but I probably just don't understand something.

Comment: I have svg icons inside my <a> links and this was capturing the bubble in IE11 until I added this. This guards IE with a css hack.

    /* needed for IE11 remove this someday This is a complete hack to only target IE! */
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        svg {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    }

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. The fix I use is to just put a transparent div over the svg. But that is not ideal of course.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used `display: block` or `display: inline-block` on the link and it worked.